# Click listener on a view on top of another

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a cardview and a list inside it. But, when I click on the cardview it doesn't receive click callbacks because the list is on top of it. Any solution to solve this?

I tried to make the list unclickable ; but it didn't work!

XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    style="@style/CardViewStyle"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_entry_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:background="@color/green_700"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            tools:text="Entry status label text" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_entry_fields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_entry_status"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_delete_entry"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view_entry_fields">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_delete_entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: post your layout, my guess if u want click event on cardview then make your list unclickable using android:clickable="false" in layout xml file

Comment: I've already done that. It didn't work. Won't post anything. Thanks!

Comment: @DivyangPanchal I've just edited the post with code.

Comment: I have check your code & its working for me

Comment: @DivyangPanchal Yes it looks totally fine. But it's not working!